# Print Single HTML Page in A4 Landscape : Extra Page w/ Chrome Linux

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm trying to print the following HTML page in A4 Landscape using Chrome:

https://www.iccube.com/downloads/A4_landscape.html

It contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; width: 297mm; height: 210mm">
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; width: 297mm; height: 210mm">
<div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; width: 297mm; height: 210mm; background-color: lightskyblue">
    Print me in A4 landscape!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, with Chrome (v96.x) on Linux it prints an extra page.

Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong with the HTML?

Note: it prints properly using Chrome on Windows.
Note: it prints properly using Firefox.

Comment: Try resetting all styles from _body_ and from _html_, add `overflow: hidden` to _div_

Comment: @Justinas I've edited the file; still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following before your html tags

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page { size: auto; margin: 0; padding 0; overflow: hidden; }
    body  { margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm; padding: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;}
</style>
```

Comment: Still the same problem.